# Create a npm package with dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-package

I have a distributed node.js project and I want to create a standalone package containing the project's domain.

First of all I created a package called "common" containing some utilities using the:

```
npm pack
```

command and creating the common.tgz file. Next I created the model.tgz file using the same method, please node that the model package use the common package so I installed it putting inside "model" in the temp folder, so the model package has the following structure:

```
|_ model
  |_ tmp
    |_common.tgz
```

It seems to work.

Now I want to import model.tgz inside my main project putting it into temp folder, but when I run the

```
npm i
```

comand I get:

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'prj_name/backend/functions/functions/tmp/common-1.0.0.tgz'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

I solved it by doing so in my main project:

```
|_ main
  |_ tmp
    |_model.tgz 
    |_tmp
      |_common.tgz
```

Since this is a little bit confusing, Is there a way to include common.tgz inside model.tgz and not need to re-import everywhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a field you can use in the package.json:

```
 "bundledDependencies":[],
```

so in my case the package model has the following package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "common": "file:tmp/common-2.0.0.tgz"
  },
  "bundledDependencies":["common"],
```

and the main project now just have:

```
- main
  |_ tmp
    |_model.tgz
```